# Postgresql indexes not used

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to understand why indexes are not used by this query:

```
SELECT 
  te.idturno
FROM turno t
JOIN turnoestado te ON t.idturno = te.idturno
ORDER BY te.idturno, te.idturnoestado
Limit 100
```

Row count for table Turno is ~1 million, and TurnoEstado is ~10 million.

Here are the index definition:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_turnoestado_idturno
  ON turnoestado USING btree (idturno);

CREATE INDEX idx_turnoestado_idturnoestado
  ON turnoestado USING btree (idturnoestado);
```

As you can see, there are two indexes for the keys used in the Order By clause, but none of them are used acording to the query plan returned by explain analyze:

```
Limit  (cost=988700.56..988700.81 rows=100 width=8) (actual time=7332.740..7332.754 rows=100 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=988700.56..1014125.36 rows=10169918 width=8) (actual time=7332.737..7332.746 rows=100 loops=1)
        Sort Key: te.idturno, te.idturnoestado
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 29kB
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=160603.86..600013.61 rows=10169918 width=8) (actual time=505.221..6279.233 rows=10169918 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (te.idturno = t.idturno)
              ->  Seq Scan on turnoestado te  (cost=0.00..178003.18 rows=10169918 width=8) (actual time=0.011..1249.563 rows=10169918 loops=1)
              ->  Hash  (cost=143894.94..143894.94 rows=1018394 width=4) (actual time=504.731..504.731 rows=1018394 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 4096  Batches: 64  Memory Usage: 571kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on turno t  (cost=0.00..143894.94 rows=1018394 width=4) (actual time=0.033..342.071 rows=1018394 loops=1)
Total runtime: 7332.824 ms
```

If I use only one key in the Order By, the result is instantaneous, the same happens if I create a multicolumn index. Why the planner does not use the indexes already created?.

P.S.: I'm using "PostgreSQL 9.3.5 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit"

Comment: Are you sure that "explain" output is the output for the SELECT statement you posted? I find that hard to believe.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall', I forgot to include the Limit. Now I replaced the original query and the Plan, please take a look.

Comment: it seems like a composite index `ON turnoestado USING btree (iturno, idturnoestado);` could help. (but since the join produces the entire 10M rows, the index would at most avoid the sort step (~1sec))

Comment: Ok @joop, I included a composite index, and indeed it's very fast. Now, going one step further, I added a where clause as "where te.estado in ('E', 'W', 'S')" that removed index usage again. Why's that?.

Comment: I found something interesting, if I replace the where by an inner join against a table containing the values 'E', 'W' and 'S' the query runs very fast.

Comment: Probably a low-cardinality column.